# Quelle préposition avant un infinitif : facile à/de dire ? What preposition to use in adjective + à/de + infinitive?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions, infinitif

Dans beaucoup de phrases, on doit utiliser la préposition « à », ou « de », mais je ne sais pas quand utiliser l'une ou l'autre.

Par exemple :

> C'est plus facile **à** lire.
> (ici: *à* et pas *de*)
>
> J'essaie **de** dormir.
>  (ici: *de* et pas *à*).

Y a-t-il une règle pour savoir lequel on doit utiliser en français ? Dans les deux cas, on mettrait le mot « *to* » en anglais.

---

When should we use *à* or *de* before an infinitive? Is there a rule?

Comment: Note qu'on peut également dire : "Il est plus facile **de** lire que d'écrire.", mais le sens est différent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### 1. Le cas particulier « être [adjectif] + de/à + [infinitif] »

Dans :

> (1) Ce livre est facile à lire.

le sujet *ce livre* peut devenir [COD](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct) de *lire* lorsqu'on décrit l'action : « Lire ce livre. »

Dans :

> (2) Il sera difficile de retrouver le chemin.

le COD de *retrouver* est *le chemin* et il n'est pas hérité de la proposition principale.
Par contre, étant donné que *le chemin* est COD, la phrase suivante évoque la même action :

> (3) Le chemin sera difficile à retrouver.

On voit ici que, parfois, *de* et *à* peuvent être utilisés pour le même verbe. Le choix se fait en déterminant si on souhaite utiliser la proposition infinitive sans objet additionnel (comme dans 2.), ou si on souhaite aussi y injecter l'objet qui est aussi sujet de la proposition principale (comme dans 1. et 3.).

**Note:** Dans les phrases suivantes :

> Il est facile de dormir.
>
> Il est facile d'oublier.

La préposition *de* est utilisée,

- soit parce que le verbe est intransitif (*dormir* n'admet pas de COD)
- soit parce qu'on ne souhaite pas préciser l'objet dont on parle (*oublier* est utilisé dans son sens le plus général).

#### 2. Autres expressions

Pour la plupart des expressions qui comportent une action, la préposition est fixée :

- *essayer de* + infinitif : *J'essaye de dormir.*
- *finir de* + infinitif : *Il a fini de faire la sieste.*
- *commencer à* + infinitif : *Ils commencent à m'énerver.*
- *chercher à* + infinitif : *Elle cherche à vendre sa voiture.*
- etc.

Voici [une liste un peu plus complète](http://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/pr/pre4.html).

On remarquera aussi que certains verbes s'utilisent sans préposition :

- *falloir* + infinitif : *Il faut faire attention.*
- *aimer* + infinitif : *J'aime manger.*
- *croire* + infinitif : *Il croit passer inaperçu.*
- etc.

---

#### 1. The special case *être* [adjective] *de/à* [infinitive]

In

> (1) Ce livre est facile à lire.

the subject *ce livre* can become the [direct object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)) of *lire* when you describe the action in the active voice: “*lire ce livre*”.

In

> (2) Il sera difficile de retrouver le chemin.

the direct object of *retrouver* is “*le chemin*”. It is not inherited from the main clause. On the other hand, given that “*le chemin*” is the direct object, the following sentence is synonymous:

> (3) Le chemin sera difficile à retrouver.

This illustrates that for the same verb, sometimes both *de* and *à* are possible. You can tell which one to use depending on whether the infinitive clause stands alone (as in (2)) or the infinitive clause includes an object from the main clause (as in (1) and (3)).

Sentences like the following use *de*:

- “Il est facile de dormir.” — the verb *dormir* is intransitive (it cannot have a direct complement).
- “Il est facile d'oublier.” — the verb *oublier* is used without an object (the sentence is about forgetting in general, not about forgetting a specific thing).

#### 2. Other expressions

In most expressions that include an action, the preposition is fixed. For example:

- *essayer de* + infinitive: “*J'essaye de dormir.”
- *finir de* + infinitive : “*Il a fini de faire la sieste.*”
- *commencer à* + infinitive : “*Ils commencent à m'énerver.*”
- *chercher à* + infinitive : “*Elle cherche à vendre sa voiture.*”

See [a more complete list](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/pr/pre4.html).

Note that some verbs don't take a preposition. For example:

- *falloir* + infinitif : “*Il faut faire attention.*”
- *aimer* + infinitif : “*J'aime manger.*”
- *croire* + infinitif : “*Il croit passer inaperçu.*”

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez So, given that the phrase is impersonal, is there any preference in formality/naturalness between "C'est facile de lire en français" and "il est facile de lire en français"?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez And why is it "C'est difficile à dire" and not "C'est difficile de dire," which is what it ought to be according to your answer here. Is *de* never used with *c'est* in impersonal expressions?

Comment: @Aerovistae: You can say “C'est difficile à dire” talking of something particular (*ce* refers to that thing), or you can say “C'est difficile de dire « abracadabra »” (*ce* is then an impersonal pronoun and introduces a general statement).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeing a clear distinction at all.

Comment: "Il est" vs "c'est" in this case, and à vs de, there is much ambiguity.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Ah missed your other source of concern. There is no much difference between “Il est difficile de…” and “C'est difficile de…”. I'd say the former is more often used in writing while the latter is usually spoken.

Comment: Rereading your answer now a few months later, it makes much more sense. Not perfectly, but mostly.

Comment: Je sais que ce poste est très vieux(?) mais j'ai une question. En français dit on"de faire/fabriquer" pour tout qu'importe le contexte? Comme(?) dans la phrase (je ne pouvais pas penser à une mieux phrase) "Il est bon de faire cette nourriture", et "Cette nourriture est bon de faire"

Comment: @Marco: La préposition (ou son abscence) dépend du verbe ou du nom qui précède, pas de celui qui suit. *Commencer à fabriquer*, *finir de fabriquer*, *tendance à fabriquer*, *interdiction de fabriquer*, *vouloir fabriquer*, etc.

Comment: Et si on disait "Cette génération a le potential de fabriquer..." Pourquoi y a t'il un de?

Answer (score 4):

Dans la phrase *“C'est plus facile à lire”* la préposition **à** se réfère au sujet désigné par **C'**

> Ce livre est plus facile **à** lire.

Alors que l'utilisation de *“de”* implique une action.

> C'est plus facile **de** lire en Français.

Comment: @F'x Que veut dire `C` dans la 1e phrase de cette réponse ?

Comment: Je fais référence au *C* apostrophe qui est la contraction de *Cela* : la phrase “C'est plus facile à lire” pourrait se dire “Cela est plus facile à lire”.

Answer (score 2):

There IS an obvious and easy way to choose between 'à' and 'de' as there is between 'begin to walk' and 'begin walking'.

When you present a choice after 'begin' or 'à' 
like in  begin to walk / sing / dance...
the important piece of information is walk or sing or dance.

When you use begin walking the most important piece of information is 'begin'. That we are talking of walking is not a surprise. We could not expect another verb in the context in which it appears.

After 'aller à ...' I have to present a choice I make.
The important piece of information is Paris/ Lyon/ Manchester ...

After 'revenir de...' There is no choice possible. I was somewhere and that is where I'm coming back from.

With 'à' a choice is presented as a piece of information. With 'de' what follows is already 'in the air', it's blocked by the context.

Teachers should read Le français déchiffré Clé du langage et des langues de Henri Adamcweski (Armand Colin) Pages 65 to 81 explain how to choose between 'à' and 'de' witout having to burden one's memory with obscure lists.

Comment: *Obvious* certainly not, although these remarks appear as relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Voici l'exemple avec "continuer" ([extrait de cet article](http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/continuer-a-ou-continuer-de-orthographe)) :

> Selon l’Académie française, l’usage de la préposition « de » serait
> plus littéraire. Il conviendrait donc d’écrire « continuer de… » pour
> un écrit plus formel. Au contraire « continuer à » semble d’un usage
> plus populaire.
>
> « continuer à » semble indiquer une action qui dure
> dans le temps alors que « continuer de » ferait plutôt référence à une
> habitude. Exemples : « Il continue à boire » (action qui dure). « Cet
> homme est un ivrogne, et, malgré ses promesses, il continue de boire »
> (habitude de boire).
>
> Le Projet Voltaire observe une distinction quant
> au confort de prononciation : on préférera l’usage de « de » pour
> éviter une liaison malheureuse ou un hiatus. Par exemple, « j’ai
> continué à appeler », qui est plus agréable sous la forme « j’ai
> continué d’appeler ».

Source : blog [lalanguefrancaise.com](http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/continuer-a-ou-continuer-de-orthographe)

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantics+of+french+prepositions%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=WUKhVtiaJsOe-wHS1p_YDA) a révéle ces articles de la Linguistique qui peuvent aider:

1. *Cognitive linguistics in the Redwoods: The expansion of a new paradigm in linguistics* (1996) par Eugene H. Casad inclut :
   [***The semantics of ‘empty prepositions’ in French***](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=16739714110991050371), par Suzanne E. Kemmer; Hava Bat-Zeev Shyldkrot, duquel les pp 347-348 disent :

> One set of problems in French is posed by the occurrence of different prepositions in similar and semantically parallel constructions.<sup>2</sup> In 
>   particular, the two most frequent prepositions, *å* and *de*, often appear 
>   in similar syntactic contexts, but in a distribution that seems entirely 
>   arbitrary. Infinitive complements, for example, may be introduced by 
>   either *å* or *de*. In some instances, the prepositions in a construction 
>   differ depending on the choice Of the main verb, as in *chercher å 
>   comprendre* 'seek to understand' and *essayer de manger* 'try to eat'. 
>   In other cases, the same verb may appear with either of the two ele- 
>   ments, as in the expressions commencer å marcher and commencer de 
>   marcher, both glossed 'to begin to walk'. Particularly in connection 
>   with infinitives, the complexity of distribution of *å* and *de* is so great 
>   that normative books are published for the general public on the topic 
>   of when to use which preposition.<sup>3</sup> In noun phrases also, both *å* and *de* 
>   can be used to link the head noun with modifying elements; for example, we find phrases like moulin *å* café 'coffee mill' and ville de 
>   Paris 'city of Paris'. What makes all of these cases problematic is the 
>   lack Of obvious and easily characterizable differences in meaning be 
>   tween the prepositions such as are found with contrasting expressions 
>   like aller å Paris 'go to Paris' and venir de Paris 'come from Paris'.

2. Les pages 147-163 dans *Syntax and Semantics of Prepositions* (2006) par Patrick Saint-Dizier  inclut: ***The syntax of French à and de: an HPSG analysis***, par Anne Abeillé, Olivier Bonami, Danièle Godard and Jesse Tseng.

Voir l'abondance des références dans les pp 162-163.

3. Les pages 59-63 dans *Syntax and Semantics of Prepositions* (2006) par Patrick Saint-Dizier 
   inclut:
   ***The theoretical status of prepositions*** par Franck Lebas
   duquel la page 65 dit:

> I have shown (Lebas 1999) that the semantics of French prepositions à and
>   de can be described as two particular ways of interpreting a sequence of two
>   words. What is characteristic of à is to impose a *conceptual distance* between
>   the terms it puts in relation, and X-de-Y states that Y is a context for interpreting
>   X. This kind of theoretical proposition is easy to accept in the case of very
>   abstract and grammatical prepositions. As a general, grammatical structuring
>   of semantic elements is a satisfactory way of describing in technical terms the
>   concept of linguistic abstractness. But when it comes to more colourful prepositions,
>   it appears strange and meaningless to say that what is to constitute a
>   semantic relation (relation of inclusion in the case of *in*) is to be viewed as a
>   grammatical structuring. Indeed, the semantics of these colourful prepositions
>   is not transformed in grammatical structuring; it is only *interpreted* as such.
>   Les prépositions abstraites en français.

Voir l'abondance des références dans la p 73, qui inclut:

> Cadiot, P. (1997). *Les prépositions abstraites en français*. Paris: Armand Colin.

4. Les pp 171-190 de *Adpositions:
   Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives* (2008)
   edité par Dennis Kurzon, Silvia Adler inclut :
   **French prepositions *à* and *de* in infinitival complements** par Lidia Fraczak

Voir l'abondance des références dans la p 190.

Answer (score -1):

J'essaie de dormir. Le choix du verbe 'dormir' est bloqué par le contexte, la situation. Je suis allongé, couché, dans un lit... il est tard...

C'est plus facile à ...
                       lire, comprendre, expliquer, commenter, traduire...
Après 'à', je présente mon choix comme information nouvelle.

S'il est tard, que je suis dans un lit 'dormir' n'est pas présenté comme une information nouvelle. J'essaie de dormir est une façon de dire que je n'y arrive pas, qu'il y a trop de bruit, que je ne veux pas qu'on me dérange.

C'est plus facile de lire près de la fenêtre. On n'est plus au moment du choix du verbe 'lire'. Ce moment est dépassé. On cherche le meilleur endroit pour lire, avec le plus de jour (= lumière) possible. L'idée de lecture devra dans ce cas être contenue dans le contexte.

Viens! Ce sera plus facile à lire (observer, déchiffrer, voir...) près de la fenêtre. 'à' parce que le choix de 'lire' n'est pas ici bloqué par le contexte.

D'où l'intérêt de rechercher des exemples authentiques = non fabriqués exprès pour illustrer une explication, comme c'est malheureusement le cas ici.