# Utilisation de « de » ou « à » pour un complément d'appartenance ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, prépositions

Je me demandais en écoutant les gens parler si quand ils disaient les exemples suivants c'était correct.

> "La voiture à François Hollande est trop belle !"
>
> "L'enfant à Nicolas Sarkozy chante le rock."

Est-ce que quand on dit ça on a vraiment tort. Je sais qu'on m'a répété plusieurs fois de dire "de" dans ce genre de cas. J'aimerais bien cerner la différence de leur utilisation.

J'ai déjà vu cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/279/une-regle-pour-lusage-de-a-vs-de?rq=1)! Mais ça ne répond pas exactement à ma question, car j'aimerais savoir plus pour les choses qui appartiennent aux gens et non pour leur utilisation après un verbe.

Merci à vous !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La forme correcte est *de* :

> La voiture de François Hollande est très belle.
>   L'enfant de Nicolas Sarokzy chante le rock.

L'utilisation de *à* pour signifier l'appartenance est familière, et même principalement enfantine, à la rigueur adolescente (au moins en France). Je n'ai jamais entendu d'adulte l'utiliser, sauf pour prendre volontairement un style enfantin.

Pareil pour l'utilisation de *trop* au lieu de *très* pour un superlatif d'intensité.

Comment: Oui merci. Mais je souhaiterais comprendre pourquoi. Quelles sont les règles grammaticales pour différencier?

Comment: @Geekasaur Ce n'est pas une règle grammaticale mais une règle d'usage. La préposition *à* a beaucoup de sens, mais pas l'appartenance, sauf en langue familière où elle peut remplacer *de*.

Comment: Ah! Merci! ça me soulage de savoir ça je pensais que c'était plus compliqué. :)

Comment: Au Québec, la forme avec "à" est utilisée fréquemment autant par les adultes que par les enfants. J'irais même jusqu'à dire qu'on l'entend aussi, sinon plus souvent que "de" à l'oral.

Comment: "sauf pour prendre volontairement un style enfantin."... ou pour chanter "La bite à Dudule" :-)

Answer (score 6):

Grevisse relève différent cas pour *à* marquant l'appartenance :

- *à* suivi d'un pronom personnel (*Il a un style **à lui***, Ac.)
- certaines expressions figées, les unes anciennes, les autres récentes et ressenties comme familière (*bête à bon Dieu*, *fils à papa*, *bande à Baader*)

Il signale que ces expressions viennent soit de la tradition (*à* marquant l'appartenance était commun jusqu'au XVI<sup>e</sup> s. et est devenu rare au siècle suivant) soit du parler populaire, où cet usage reste très vivant à peu près partout mais apparaît rarement à l'écrit.

Il note que le refrain que V. Hugo met dans le bouche de Gravroche (*Je suis tombé par terre, c'est la faute à Voltaire, le nez dans le ruisseau, c'est la faute à Rousseau*) a certainement contribué à faire de *la faute à* une expression simplement familière, mais il doute que ça explique tous les exemples qu'il cite (dont un autre chez Hugo, *c'est la faute à l'Assemblée* dans Napoléon le Petit).

Comment: +1 pour la citation de Grevisse . Merci :)