# « Qu'est-ce que » vs. « ce que »

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, québec

Depuis que j'ai appris le français « standard » en école (pour ce que ça vaut), j'emploie ces deux expressions en les différenciant comme « question ouverte » et « usage général ». Pour illustrer :

> — **Qu'est-ce que** tu veux donc ?
>   
> — **Ce que** je veux, c'est qu'on me fiche la paix !

Mais j'ai entendu à Radio-Canada Première, à plusieurs reprises, la première expression là où on s'attendrait à la deuxième. Même hier j'ai rencontré une phrase comme celle-ci :

> Alors ça c'est **qu'est-ce que** j'aime, le théâtre !

On emploie parfois des questions comme si elles étaient des groupes nominaux (p. ex. *L'amour, c'est mon « pourquoi »* — comparez *C'est mon « qu'est-ce que j'aime »* peut-être). Mais c'est un peu bizarre et cet usage ne me semble pas en être un exemple vu l'intonation et la fréquence avec lesquelles il s'emploie.

Or je constate que les invités à Radio-Canada emploient souvent des expressions <strike>canadiennes</strike> propres à l'oral que je ne trouvais pas dans les manuels scolaires, comme celle-ci :

> J'accepte les excuses **à** Martin.

Est-ce que c'est comme ça que je dois considérer cet emploi de « qu'est-ce que » ? Est-ce courant en français canadien ? Si oui, dans quels registres et contextes ? Cela se trouve-t-il hors du Canada ?

Pour clarifier, je ne cherche pas à savoir si cet usage soit fautif selon la grammaire standard ; je sais qu'il l'est. Je voudrais aller au-delà de ce que peuvent rapporter les approches prescriptivistes.

Comment: I often say something like: "Qu'est-ce qu'il est beau!". Here, the phrase "qu'est-ce que ..." is not a question but an intensifer. Your example looks like a variant of this intensifying expression. The exclamation mark at the end says it all.

Comment: @Alone-zee Hm, je ne crois pas que ce soit le même phénomène.

Comment: Concernant l'énoncé au sujet du choix de la préposition _à_ avec Martin, voir aussi généralement l'[appartenance](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/3011) et l'attribution, avec un [résumé](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/2811.htm) de certains [autres](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/279/3177) cas (voir remarque 1 au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)) où c'est employé, et aussi à ne pas manquer [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/rdp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=&page=../preposition) !

Comment: @LukeSawczak Puis-je écrire une réponse par rapport à l'usage en France, ou cela te paraît hors-sujet ?

Comment: @Mistalis Absolument que ce serait utile. La raison pour laquelle j'attends plus de réponses à ce moment est en effet que j'en souhaite une qui donne un point de vue un peu plus circonspect. Enfin, la réponse correcte que j'envisageais devra expliquer pourquoi j'entends cet usage ici à Radio-Canada, mais il se peut que je me trompe sur son statut "canadien" comme j'ai fait avec cet "à" dessus dont l'usage s'explique sans référence à la région !

Comment: @LukeSawczak J'ai tâché d'illustrer un petit peu l'usage dans les radios françaises dans ma réponse. Je m'étends un peu (hors-sujet) dans la fin de ma réponse, mais je trouvais le sujet intéressant. Un avis québecois sur les expressions que j'ai citées m'intéresse également !

Comment: Les exemples présentés dans cette question et ses réponses me font penser à ce que j'imagine jacoballens cherchait en posant [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36369) (que j'ai édité en espérant de la tirer de l'oubi car, comme la votre, je la trouve bien intéressante. [Votez pour la sauver, SVP!]) (Re "J'accepte les excuses à Martin": that makes me think of the "weird" (imo, as an anglo)  "à" in "Pardonner à qqn" ="je pardonne à Martin," & I wonder if all the anti-descriptivists in the room realize that "je pardonne Martin" is also considered wrong by "grammairiens"?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further reading and contact with French-Canadian speakers have given me a more nuanced view of the use of *qu'est-ce que* other than in an interrogative phrase.

It's clear from the other answers that in France, this *tournure* is regarded as strictly incorrect. Whether people on the street use it despite official censure remains outside my sphere.

- *(Survenant's comments are very intriguing and develop this censure further:* Le bon usage (14) *lists a few authors who use it, yet says their example is "not to be imitated".)*

In Québec, the Office de la langue française says that « on rencontre parfois, surtout dans la langue orale » this phenomenon. However, it takes the position that this usage is « critiqué » and [advises against it](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=qu%27est-ce%20que&id=3281):

> - Dominique t’a demandé **ce que** tu désires recevoir pour Noël. 
>     
>    (plutôt que : **qu’est-ce que** tu désires recevoir)

Nevertheless, it is indeed common in actual usage: not only among children, but also among adults, including schoolteachers, private citizens interviewed on radio, and marking supervisors for the Test des compétences linguistiques issued to students in Ontario, based on my anecdotal experience.

It would thus be appropriate to identify this usage to learners as belonging to « langage populaire », but not to regard its use in casual conversation as a sign of poor education or bad speech habits.

Any clarification or details people want to add to this answer are welcome.

Comment: Ne vous inquiétez pas, en bon ergoteur je ne saurais pas promouvoir un usage que mes profs au lycée déconseillaient ;) C'est plutôt dans le but d'avoir une éthique de linguistique descriptiviste, ce qui est normal sur ce site.

Comment: Je ne sais pas si ce que tu décris en question (_Alors ça c'est qu'est-ce que j'aime, le théâtre !_) se compare à l'interr. indirecte de la BDL dans le sens où il n'y a pas d'interr. dans la première mais je comprends qu'il y a la même transposition. En ce qui concerne le propos de la BDL, qui ne dit pas _au Québec_ ici, voir LBU14 §420 référant à Renchon, _Études de syntaxe descriptive_, II, Gr. et G. disent de voir la biblio. juste avant §381 p. 218-219. LBU14 dit que ds. l'interrogation partielle en langue soignée ces introducteurs sont _évités généralement_ mais de bon usage jusqu'au 18e.

Comment: _Disons en peu de mots qu'est-ce que l'enfer._ (Bossuet). Mais LBU dit qu'il ne faudrait ps imiter : _Il se demandait qu'est-ce qui remplacerait cela._ (Hugo, Misér.) ; _J'ai osé regarder pour savoir qui est-ce qui osait vivre où elle avait vécu._ (Lamartine) ; _Nous aurions bien voulu deviner comment elle se déroulerait et aussi qu'est-ce qui arriverait après._ (Beauvoir) ; _Nous retrouvons intacte la question de savoir qu'est-ce qui compose et créé les titres vrais._ (Maurras) ; _Chaque personnage de cette grande page peinte serait bien embarrassé de dire qu'est-ce qu'il y fait._ (Claudel).

Comment: Reste que ces grands l'ont dit... C'est bien intéressant.

Answer (score 5):

Oui, et ben :

> Alors ça c'est qu'est-ce que j'aime, le théâtre !

c'est clairement ce qu'il ne faut pas dire ! Je ne dis pas *clairement* **qu'est-ce qu'il** *ne faut pas dire* ! :) Il faudrait dire:

> Alors ça, c'est ce que j'aime, le théâtre !

J'ai entendu beaucoup ce genre de tournure dans des films en canadien. Mais en France, c'est vraiment pas bien. Bouh. Il ne faut pas dire:

> C'est qu'est-ce que je dis. 
>   C'est qu'est-ce que je fais.

Beurk. Beurk. Beurk. Très très vulgaire. Il faut dire:

> C'est ce que je dis.
>    C'est ce que je fais.

Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette histoire...
Mais vous pouvez dire:

> Qu'est-ce que j'aime le théatre. Qu'est-ce que je suis beau.

Quant au *à* pour le *de*, ça se dit beaucoup, ça ne s'écrit pas. "La pipe à papa", "les bottes à maman"...

Comment: À voir si on est devant la même construction  quand on dit « les excuses à Martin » (c.a.d. les excuses qui viennent de Martin) et « les bottes à Martin » (c.a.d. les bottes qui sont à Martin). En France on entend beaucoup « les bottes à Martin » (même si ce n'est pas considéré comme correct), mais pas du tout « J'accepte les excuses à Martin. »

Comment: Voulez-vous dire << mes excuses à Martin>> pour <<mes excuses vont à Martin>> ?

Comment: Je comprends « J'accepte les excuses à Martin » comme des les excuses qui viennent de Martin. Non ?

Comment: "À voir" m'a fait supposer que vous pourriez admettre le *à* pour les excuses avant que vous ne modifiiez votre commentaire pour ajouter la dernière phrase. Je ne suis pas vraiment convaincu par le *à* pour "venant de" (je le prends pour un possessif) mais plutôt pour "allant à" comme dans "mes pensées vont à Laure". On ne dit pas "j'accepte les excuses à Martin"  pasque quand on accepte des excuses on essaie d'être poli et de faire une belle phrase. Non ?

Comment: Concernant le dernier point, c'est commun de l'entendre au Québec.

Answer (score 1):

> Est-ce que c'est comme ça que je dois considérer cet emploi de «
>   qu'est-ce que » ?

Que ce soit pour *"Alors ça c'est qu'est-ce que j'aime, le théâtre !"* ou *"J'accepte les excuses à Martin"*, je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'une évolution de la langue. Il s'agit de mon point de vue de **fautes de français**.
Une évolution de la langue est censée apporter quelque chose de nouveau, qui ne pouvait pas être exprimé auparavant : elle pallie un manque. Ici, comme tu l'as à très juste titre souligné, il faudrait dire "Alors ça, c'est **ce que j'aime** le théâtre", et bien sûr "les excuses **de** Martin". Ces changements à la langue n'apportent pas plus de sens à la phrase.

> Se trouve-t-il hors du Canada ?

Je ne connais pas Radio-Canada, mais sur des radios françaises, j'entends (malheureusement) assez souvent des fautes de ce genre.

> C'est qu'est-ce que je vais faire. -> C'est ce que je vais faire.
>   Je vais au traiteur. -> Je vais chez le traiteur.

Parfois, j'entends aussi des *"**Au jour d'aujourd'hui**, il est temps de se préoccuper du climat"*, expression très en vogue en ce moment, et pourtant [à bannir de son vocabulaire](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/01/09/37003-20170109ARTFIG00002-les-expressions-a-bannir-au-bureau-au-jour-d-aujourd-hui.php).

Mais aussi *"Cette assemblée constituante est une assemblée qui se veut avant tout démocratique [...]"*, que l'on pourrait facilement simplifier en *"Cette assemblée constituante se  veut avant tout démocratique"*.

À noter que ces expressions sont souvent prononcées par des politiques français. Je ne comprends pas réellement comment elles sont apparues, ni pourquoi elles sont tant utilisées (je suppose que c'est tout simplement pour rendre les phrases plus compliquées, plus longues, plus verbeuses — chose que les politiques savent très bien faire).

Quoi qu'il en soit, je ne trouve pas sous prétexte que des fautes de français soient faites à la radio, que celles-ci doivent entrer dans la langue française. Je ne suis pas spécialement résistant au changement, mais il faut tâcher de garder un minimum de rigueur dans la langue de Molière, tout de même ... :-)