# Are there any notable mistakes in French that are made by enough otherwise well-spoken natives that they are acceptable to all but strict grammarians?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, argot

For two well-known examples of this in English, it’s common to say/hear

> “Me and my friend” or “Him and I” (both incorrect)

instead of

> “My friend and I” and “He and I” (both correct).

Similarly, I'm wondering if there are any (and if so, what they would be) prime, well-known examples of non-grammatical French structures that, while "technically wrong,” are so commonly (mis)used by French people that they are considered by many, if not most, to be "basically correct"?

Comment: On trouve l'interdit de l'Ac., ce qui n'est pas une opinion. http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-jour-daujourdhui

Comment: « [et autres...](https://www.monbestseller.com/actualites-litteraire/7602-ecrire-corriger-expression-et-ou-autres) » comme dans « Une soupe à base de carottes, poireaux et autres patates. »

Comment: Sujet singulier collectif + verbe au singulier, comme dans « **la moitié** des électeurs **est** de gauche », qui devrait être « **la moitié** des électeurs **sont** de gauche ». On trouve très souvent ce genre d'atrocité dans les médias. Voir https://www.logilangue.com/public/Site/clicGrammaire/CollectifAccord.php

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Le problème que vous soulevez n'est caractérisé par des atrocités, cela parce que la logique de sa solution n'est pas irréprochable; elle est en fait caduc ; (http://www.adomcours.com/orthographe-laccord-du-collectif-singulier/). « Une vingtaine de personnes sont venues. », « Une dizaine était en retard. » : le noyau reste « vingtaine », c'est « vingtaine » le sujet. La grammaire traditionnelle, même si elle ne parait pas satisfaisante à toujours le mérite de la consistance.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Le lien que tu mets stipule justement que l'exemple que tu donnes n'est pas une faute, et que les deux formes sont autorisées. Tout dépend en réalité de l'accent que tu veux y placer.

Comment: @Strebler Je sais bien, mais dans l'exemple que je donne, ce n'est pas la moitié qui vote, ce sont *les* électeurs. Il faut avoir l'esprit bien tordu pour choisir le singulier. En pratique, les journalistes choisissent *toujours* le singulier. C'est une application abusive d'autres règles de grammaire (accord sujet/verbe), alors que ça devrait être choisi intelligemment. C'est en cela que c'est, à mon avis, erroné. Disons que ça fait partie des points litigieux (et encore, je n'ai pas sorti le classique *"autant pour moi"*...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are, as in all languages, see for example:

> Malgré que

Or pleonasms such as:

> Au jour d’aujourd’hui

However, note that **they are incorrect** even if you may sometimes hear them. They should be seen as common mistakes.

---

More explanation about "Au jour d’aujourd’hui" (Thanks comments! [source: academie-francaise](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-jour-daujourdhui))

> *Emplois fautifs*
>
> Cette formule jouant sur la redondance a une résonance familière et
>   plaisante. Pour parler de la journée présente ou de celle que l’on
>   évoque, on préfèrera dire **Aujourd’hui** ou **Ce jour**. On peut aussi
>   recourir à la tournure ancienne *Ce jour d’hui*.

Comment: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-jour-daujourdhui _  Sachez donc qu’au jour d’aujourd’hui on ne remue de fonds que dans l’industrie — (George Sand, Le Meunier d’Angibault‎, 1847) https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_jour_d%E2%80%99aujourd%E2%80%99hui

Answer (score 0):

Many people use the subjonctive after "après que". We have to use the indicative. e.g.:

Wrong: *Après que je sois allé chez Jules.*
Correct: *Après que je suis allé chez Jules.*

[Après que Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/apres-que)

Comment: I confess I would have use wrong sentence (shame on me).

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/avant-que-et-apr%c3%a8s-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif