# D'où vient l'utilisation de « de » pour un complément d'appartenance ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, histoire, évolution

Si l'on regarde le contenu de la discussion ci-dessous on remarque que précédemment on utilisait la préposition *à*.
D'où vient l'utilisation du *de* ?

[Utilisation de « de » ou « à » pour un complément d'appartenance ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3011/utilisation-de-de-ou-%c3%a0-pour-un-compl%c3%a9ment-dappartenance)

Answer (score 3):

D'après les historiens de la langue, l'usage de la préposition *de* pour exprimer un **génitif** est attesté pour la première fois ca 1050 dans la "Chançun de Willame" :
"*Plainums ensemble le doel **de** nostre ami*"

(Nota : Il s'agit certainement d'une sacrée surprise pour le copiste puisqu'il se trompe dans l'écriture de la phrase suivante... Lire [ici](https://www.persee.fr/doc/rbph_0035-0818_1945_num_24_1_1710).)

Cet usage particulier de la préposition est bien logiquement inspiré par son usage déjà bien ancré pour exprimer l'origine, la provenance. (usage attesté dans *Les serment de Strasbourg* (ca 850))

Ce dernier est directement issu du ***de* latin**, utilisé avec l'ablatif pour rendre le même sens.

Comment: Nota pour les puristes : Oui! dans la première attestation, nous avons affaire avec un *génitif objectif*. Mais, pas plus que le latin, le français ne marque de différence avec l'expression d'un *génitif subjectif*.