# When should “capacité à” or “capacité de” be used?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I had written this sentence while practicing on Lang-8, and someone corrected it to the second version below:

> Mon but est d'écrire de deux à trois textes chaque semaine, avec l'intention d'améliorer ma capacité de construire des phrases.

#2

> Mon but est d'écrire de deux à trois textes chaque semaine, avec **pour** intention d'améliorer ma capacité **à** construire des phrases.

I don't really understand either of these corrections. *avec pour* seems odd to me, having two prepositions side-by-side, and given my understanding of [à vs de](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/279/une-r%C3%A8gle-pour-lusage-de-%C3%A0-vs-de), I thought I was in the right to have used *de*. Can someone explain these two corrections?

Comment: « **Avec** l'intention / pour intention » est un anglicisme qu'on entend parfois, mais il est plus courant de dire « [**dans**  l'intention de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/dans%20l'intention%20de)  ». Pour ce qui est de « capacité à » ou « capacité de » je ne pourrais pas mieux expliquer que ce que tu trouveras [ici](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/capacite-a-de-a23272460) et [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3427), donc les deux sont corrects, **à** plus fréquent devant un inifinitif même si certains considèrent que **de** est plus correct.

Comment: I disagree with the avec pour intention like that.  Yours was fine. That said, I would leave out your second DE: Mon but est d'écrire deux à trois textes....I also agree with capacité à/de

Comment: You should know already that only one question should be asked at a time. Did you think the two changes were related?

Comment: No, fine, we all make mistakes, yes, I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first correction, #1 and #2 are acceptable, but the best wording is:

> Mon but est d'écrire de deux à trois textes chaque semaine, **dans 
>   l'intention** d'améliorer ...

The second correction (*"ma capacité à"*) is unneeded, however, because "être capable à faire" is incorrect: the right expression is "**être capable de**". Note that before an infinitive verb, the two prepositions are accepted.

If you had used "aptitude" instead of "capacité" (the two words are synonyms), you would have written "**mon aptitude à**", because you are "**apte à faire**" (and not "apte de faire", which is incorrect.

Comment: I think I edited this correctly, catch me if I'm wrong. You're saying I had it right, *ma capacité de faire qch* ?

Comment: @Aerovistae - You are right. I made an inversion: the "correction" wasn't justified. For example, "work capacity" will be translated to "capacité de travail". However, the preposition "à" is often used before a verb, e.g. "capacité à travailler en équipe".

Comment: Well *à* has been taking over over the last decades. I would definitely not recommend *de* in this particular context. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sa+capacit%C3%A9+de+faire%2Csa+capacit%C3%A9+%C3%A0+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csa%20capacit%C3%A9%20de%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csa%20capacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20faire%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Par ailleurs *dans l'intension* et *avec l'intension* ont toujours coexisté et il y a une subtile nuance de sens. Comparer *Je pars avec l'intention…* et *Je pars dans l'intention…*. Dans la phrase donnée *dans l'intention* sonne complètement faux pour moi. On ne peut pas avoir un but dans une intention.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez -The slight difference I see between "dans l'intention" and "avec l'intention" is that the first introduces of a main reason for acting, whilst the second may refer to a secondary target.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - For "capacité à/de", looking at [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans+l%27intention%2C+avec+l%27intention&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdans%20l%27%20intention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavec%20l%27%20intention%3B%2Cc0), the (small) difference in the figures is not a justification for a "correction".

Comment: I don't know which of the two issues you refer to (your last link was *dans* vs *avec*). Even if you don't know French, ngrams is in both cases is a good justification of the coexistance of two constructions. We talk of printed books here. You just need to make sure that in most of the examples the prepositions are used as we think and not accidentally attached to an other particular construction. But you are right, ngrams doesn't explain when to use which construction, or if they are completely interchangable.

Answer (score 1):

*avec pour intention* et *avec pour intention* sont tous les deux corrects, mais sonnent mal.

Comme indiqué plusieurs fois, *dans l'intention* est l'expression idoine.

*Avoir pour but*, *dans l'intention* sont inversés. On dirait plutôt, *avoir l'intention* (la volonté de), *dans le but de*, avec *pour objectif de*, *pour*, *afin de* .

*de* dans *de deux à trois* est inutile.

> Mon intention est d'écrire deux à trois textes chaque semaine, dans
>   le but de/avec comme objectif/pour/afin d'améliorer ma capacité à construire des
>   phrases.