# Quels sont précisément les contextes d'emploi des prépositions à/de avec « capacité », suivi d'un infinitif ?

Tags: prépositions, articles, infinitif, lexique, déterminants

[Quand](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/national/201901/26/01-5212516-deux-bombardiers-russes-volant-pres-des-cotes-nord-americaines-escortes-par-des-chasseurs-du-norad.php) des bombardiers stratégiques russes [Tu-160](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-160) « [Blackjack](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_OTAN) » entrent dans une [*zone d'identification de défense aérienne*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=AIR%20DEFENSE%20IDENTIFICATION%20ZONE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) [près](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Defense_Identification_Zone_(North_America)) des côtes nord-américaines (dans ce cas-ci dans une ADIZ canadienne), le *Commandement de la défense aérospatiale de l'Amérique du Nord* ([NORAD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commandement_de_la_d%C3%A9fense_a%C3%A9rospatiale_de_l%27Am%C3%A9rique_du_Nord)) s'y [intéresse](https://twitter.com/Norad_Northcom/status/1089216512596922368) de près :

> La priorité du NORAD est de défendre le Canada et les États-Unis.
>   Notre **capacité à protéger** nos nations commence par la détection, la
>   localisation et l'identification d'aéronefs d'intérêt approchant de
>   l'espace aérien américain et canadien.
>
> [NORAD's top priority is defending Canada and the United States. Our ability to protect our nations starts with successfully detecting, tracking, and positively identifying aircraft of interest approaching U.S. and Canadian airspace. ([CBC.ca](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/airforce-arctic-canada-u-s-russia-1.4994702))]
>
> [ Général [Terrence J. O'Shaughnessy](http://www.norad.mil/Leadership/Article-View/Article/1531571/general-terrence-j-oshaughnessy-usaf/), commandant du NORAD, dans *La Presse*, je souligne ]

En ce qui a trait au choix de la préposition (*à* ou *de*) avec le mot *capacité* on peut lire que :

> Lorsque *capacité* est suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif, on fait souvent
>   précéder ce verbe de la préposition *de*. Mais c’est la préposition
>   *à* qui apparaît plus naturellement dans **certains contextes**.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* de l'OQLF, [article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3427)
>   consulté le 26 janvier 2019, je souligne ]

---

Une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17589) plus sommaire a déjà été posée mais on n'a pas obtenu de réponse satisfaisante parce qu'on a préféré reformuler ou traiter d'un autre élément moins pertinent...

- Peut-on donner une idée de la distribution de la fréquence pour l'une et l'autre préposition avec *capacité* ; **quels sont précisément ces contextes** ; peut-on s'appuyer sur une (des) source(s) crédible(s) [directement](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/when-should-capacit%C3%A9-%C3%A0-or-capacit%C3%A9-de-be-used#comment33158_17589) (et non sur un site web qui liste 19 sources bibliographiques) ; ces constats s'inscrivent-ils dans un usage ou un règle de plus grande portée (cohérence : voir questions liées [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/279)) et brièvement le cas échéant lequel ou laquelle ?

Answer (score 1):

En se basant sur la collection totale d'exemples du TLFi, quasiment toutes les occurrences (plus d'une vingtaine)  suivies de « à » le sont lorsque « capacité » est combiné avec un verbe. Pour obtenir le petit corpus de ces exemple chercher « capacité à » dans le TLFi (liens au corpus non possible).

D'après un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capacit%C3%A9+%C3%A0%2Ccapacit%C3%A9+%C3%A0+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20produire%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20cet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20agir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20r%C3%A9pondre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20prendre%3B%2Cc0) cela semble généralement vrai, très souvent le nom est combiné avec un verbe plutôt que l'article défini.

« De » se trouve lorsque le mot combiné est un nom sans article ; cette combinaison est cependant beaucoup plus rare que celle avec le verbe ; on n'en trouve qu'une dans toute la collection d'exemples du [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/search.exe?23;s=217282695;cat=1;m=capacit%82+de;) (**capacité de production**, *terme défini*)
Il n'y pas de tendance selon laquelle l'article ne serait pas utilisé ; cela est confirmé par l'[ngram pour « capacité de »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capacit%C3%A9+de%2Ccapacit%C3%A9+de+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapacit%C3%A9%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccapacit%C3%A9%20de%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20production%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20travail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20l%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20ceux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacit%C3%A9%20de%20r%C3%A9sistance%3B%2Cc0): il y a des occurrences d'article.

Le cas particulier d'une spécialisation du terme à l'administration de l'enseignement n'est pas, semble-t-il, véritablement dissociable du cas général ;

(TLFi)  Brevet élémentaire. Brevet qui sanctionnait un certain niveau d'études primaires supérieures et conférait un titre de **capacité à l'enseignement**. (Brevet élémentaire.)

Les évidences obtenues ne sont pas celles d'une étude finale de la question mais indiquent très fortement que seule la préposition « **à** » devrait être utilisée lorsque le mot qui suit est un verbe, les occurrences de « **de** » étant à considérer inhabituelles et *créant un climat d'incertitude*. Les combinaisons avec les noms ne relèvent pas d'un processus très productif lorsque le nom n'est pas précédé d'un article  mais la préposition à utiliser semble très surement devoir être « **de** ». Lorsqu'un article est utilisé pour le nom qui suit, la préposition est « **à** », sauf lorsque la relation selon laquelle « de » est compris fait de « capacité » un attribut du nom en combinaison.
  Cela me semble être ce qu'il faut retenir de cette petite recherche.