# « à faire qqch » vs « de faire qqch »

Tags: prépositions, verbes

J'ai des problèmes pour différencier l'utilisation des mots « à » et « de » avant un verbe. Quand est-ce qu'on utilise l'un et quand l'autre ? Est-ce qu'il y a un sujet de grammaire à ce propos pour que je puisse rechercher plus ?

Comment: Cf http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/279/une-r%c3%a8gle-pour-lusage-de-%c3%a0-vs-de-1-entre-un-adjectif-et-un-infinitif

Answer (score 3):

La préposition me semble surtout dépendre du verbe conjugué qui la précède, et non du verbe à l'infinitif qui la suit.

Avec *inciter à* :

> Il m'incite à faire du sport.

Avec *demander de* :

> Il me demande de faire du sport.

Comment: Il faudrait donc juste connaitre par coeur quelle préposition [suit/peut suivre] chaque verbe, sans règle particulière ?

Comment: @Random En tout cas, quand je dis *il m'incite à...*, j'ai bien l'impression que je peux mettre n'importe quel verbe à l'infinitif derrière, alors que *il m'incite de...* n'existe pas.

Comment: Oui c'est sûr, je fais le parallèle avec "to look at" en anglais. Si on veut dire "regarder", on a pas le choix de la préposition. Changer de prépopsition change le sens ("to look for" n'a rien à voir)... mon commentaire est une vrai question :) C'est tout de même étrange qu'il n'y ait aucune "logique"...

Comment: Simon a tout à fait raison, en français c'est le verbe qui précède qui détermine la préposition. En anglais, c'est le contraire, parce qu'il s'agit de "phrasal verbs" qui changent de signification selon la préposition. (Il y a très peu de verbes français comme ça, par ex. penser à vs penser de.)

Comment: It seems that some verbs (like *continuer*) permit either “à” or “de” regardless of the following infinitive (“continuer à /de parler”, for example).  If that’s true, is it just a matter of personal choice or is there a nuance between the two? …  Also, some verbs (like *demander*) seem to use “à” to mean one thing (to ask permission for oneself to do something) and “de” to mean another thing (to ask another person to do something), so maybe there are some rules (whether logical or not) as I think @Random is aptly suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

*à* et *de* devant un verbe (à l'infinitif) dépendent **du verbe qui précède**.

Dans le cas demandé, il s'agit de verbes suivis d'une forme à l'infinitif.

**Ces verbes sont en quantité réduite:**

- verbes modaux (pouvoir, vouloir, devoir);
- verbes de perception, de sensation, de pensée, d'affirmation, ....

**Beaucoup sont transitifs.**

Ces verbes peuvent soit être :

- transitifs, donc sans préposition: Je pense courir ce marathon, je veux manger cette salade, Je dois partir ;
- intransitifs avec la préposition à : Je pense à courir ce marathon, je réfléchis à changer de travail, ...
- intransitifs avec la préposition de: Je parle de venir demain.

D'autres formes avec d'autres propositions existent peut-être avec des formes infinitives, mais je n'en vois pas dans l'immédiat.

De manière générale, les deux prépositions les plus courantes des verbes intransitifs sont *à* et *de*.

Answer (score 0):

Le *à* est utilisé quand on veut désigner un lieu précis. Ex: *Je vais à la mer* (on utilise *chez* pour designer un lieu variable Ex: *Chez un ami*) et *de* est utilisé pour désigner un besoin rélié à une action. Ex : *J'ai besoin de faire quelque chose*.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment la question.

Comment: L'exemple donné dans la réponse de Simon Déchamps, montre que cette réponse est au moins partiellement fausse ou incomplète. Ex: « je pense à ... » ne désigne pas du tout un lieu non plus.

Comment: à + un lieu = complément circonstanciel de lieu (on peut aussi utiliser de, vers, etc.) . Cet emploi de à est différent de la préposition à associée à un verbe, ce qui constituait la question. -1