# When does 'de' precede an infinitive?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, adjectifs, de

I would like to say the following sentence in French: That is kind of you to say.

Using Google translate I obtain *C'est gentil à vous **de** dire.* If this is the *equivalent* translation in French then I have a question. I do not understand why **de** is used. What grammatical rule is being used that causes *de* to be there?

Comment: Well an equivalent in idiomatic French (as opposed to “Google French") could be *C'est gentil de votre part de l'avoir dit*. Your question about the grammar at play still stands though. But maybe this already answers your question  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/279 ?

Answer (score 1):

> C'est gentil à vous de dire

This sentence is neither correct nor idiomatic.

1. "*C'est gentil à vous*" is not correct, use ether "*C'est gentil **de votre part***" or just "*C'est gentil*"
2. You can't just end you sentence with "*de dire*". You can use "*de dire ça*" or "*de l'avoir dit*".

You can skip both, as a response to a compliment or something nice it would be idiomatic to just say "*C'est gentil*".

---

Howerver, your question stills holds because you **can** use *de* after "*C'est gentil*".

> C'est gentil **de** me dire ça.
>
> C'est gentil **de** m'aider à porter ma valise.

Here it translates with *to* : "*It's nice of you **to** help me carry my luggage.*"

Answer (score 0):

Grammaticalement donc :

2 verbes > 2 propositions.

- C'est gentil à vous : Proposition principale,

La proposition suivante (subordonnée) va venir **compléter** la principale (préciser la raison de l'expression principale), on l'appellera *proposition complétive*

Pour introduire cette subordonnée, on a besoin d'un... **subordonnant** (dans le cas d'une *complétive*, certains parleront de... **complémenteur**.)

C'est très exactement le rôle que joue ce *de* qui t'interroge ici. Il introduit la subordonnée complétive. (Qui se trouve ici de plus infinitive)