# What does “à” mean in this sentence?

Tags: usage, prépositions, à

I was reading L’Etranger by Albert Camus and came upon this sentence:

> Quand elle était à la maison, maman passait son temps **à** me suivre des yeux en silence.

The usage of **à** I am referring to is in bold.

I reckon it means “by”.

Also, sometimes, **de** is also used to mean *by*. When to use **à** and **de** respectively when translating *by*.

Comment: Can you give some examples of uses of "by" where you expect it should be translated by "de" or "à" ?

Comment: Generally speaking, that site is nice to read for à, https://www.thoughtco.com/a-vs-de-french-prepositions-4080520 (it give a lot of example)

Comment: TLFi: "(Le temps) passe à + inf./en + subst. Être occupé, utilisé à. Nos dernières heures "de Mittelsinn, avant la nuit, passèrent à rassembler des provisions (Ambrière, Gdes vac., 1946, p.366)"

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to translate the word "à", it might be better to understand the phrase as a whole.

The phrase *passer son temps* means "to spend a lot of time, and even much more than one should reasonably expect". There is a nuance of reproach or complaint, so it differs from the neutral phrase *passer du temps*.

> Mes enfants passent leur temps sur leur téléphone

You can use this phrase with a verb to specify "what" one spends too much time on. As often in French, this is done by adding the preposition *à* with an infinitive.

> J'en ai marre, je passe mon temps à nettoyer la maison

As to your question when to use *à* or *de* in such cases (I presume with an infinitive form), I am afraid there is no easy answer: that is something that native speakers learn naturally, but that you, as non-native, will unfortunately need to study... There are some trends you can remember (see [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/279/quelle-pr%c3%a9position-avant-un-infinitif-facile-%c3%a0-de-dire-what-preposition-to-u)) but for a lot of adjectives, nouns or idiomatic phrases, you just need to learn it case by case.